# .NET application for blackberry?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, blackberry

i have a very simple winform application in vb.net and i was wondering how do i make it work on blackberry and other PDAs?

Comment: You just can't. Blackberries don't run Windows Mobile, or, more generally, WinCE.

Comment: if blackberry does not use the net runtimes, you might want to rebuild the app in a language that the phone understands, or see if you can find a converter that can cross code the app to the os of the blackberry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the MDS runtime and VisualStudio plug-in which you can download here: http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/rapidappdev/devtools.jsp

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this is not possible.  There is no version of the .Net runtime available for blackberry devices.

Answer (score 3):

If it is not be too difficult to convert your Winforms application to ASP.NET, you [could use that on a Blackberry](http://www.flowfinity.com/developers/blackbird.html) ...

> Flowfinity Blackbird is an add-on to
>   Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2005 that
>   empowers ASP.NET developers to deliver
>   "Wireless-Ready" applications for
>   BlackBerry®. Using unique features of
>   Visual Studio 2005, Blackbird shortens
>   the BlackBerry application development
>   learning curve for Microsoft .NET
>   developers.

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but it might help.  Also, check out [Windows Mobile](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsmobile/en-us/default.mspx).  That might fit your needs as well.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it personally, but you may look at a language such as Scala and see if you can compile code in that language for a JVM that will run on a Blackberry. One advantage is that they are working on having it output CLR bytecode also, so, in one language, you can go between .NET and Java, but, then the Winforms part will be problematic, but not insurmountable.

Answer (score 1):

If it really is a "very simple" application, you port it to BlackBerry's version of J2ME.  Since both are managed languages, it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: can you please elaborate on this

Comment: Not... really, no.  To be exceedingly vague and non-technical, my approach would be to simply look at how the app looks and acts, and mimic it using BlackBerry classes. I've done this on a number of occasions with standard J2ME apps that were coded so differently that most of the code was thrown away.  Mostly the only thing that remained was how to construct URLs for network calls.

Comment: ok in that case please recommend the J2ME compiler for blackberry

Comment: BlackBerry's website (http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/devtools.jsp) has everything you need for developing for a BlackBerry.  Their JDE (Java IDE) is a fully-integrated solution for development, building, and testing.  They also have an Eclipse plugin if that's your flavor.  The JDE comes with a compiler that can be command-line driven, and the tool for signing the resulting COD files, if they need to be signed.

Answer (score 0):

See http://code.google.com/p/csharpblackberry/
As for VB.Net development, am busy with a prototype.